# What books are available in market for learning the Windows API for GUI development with C++?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

Please give me some titles, preferably not free books.
I don't need it to be free; it would be better if published by McGraw Hill, Prentice-Hall, Springer, or any other good publisher.

Note that I'm interested here in programming with C++ only.

Comment: The Windows API is a C API, so the vast majority of books about programming to it naturally use C as the programming language.

Answer (score 3):

The classic is Petzold [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-Microsoft-Charles-Petzold/dp/157231995X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X)

Comment: Petzold covers mostly GUI-related subjects of the Windows API. Complementary to that I would recommend Jeffrey Richter's [Windows via C/C++](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0735624240), which covers basically everything else except GUI programming.

Answer (score 2):

Very few (printed) books cover use of the Windows API from C++ per se (most cover use from C, or something like .NET). You might want to take a look at Relisoft's [C++ resources](http://www.relisoft.com/cpp.html) page though. They have a free online book *and* their own library (RSWL) that implements most of the ideas in the book. If you really want to pay for it, I believe you can get a printed copy through Amazon that you'd have to pay for.